# Powering Raspberry Pi Zero from a USB Power Bank

Tags: power-supply, usb-power, pi-zero

I want to purchase a USB Power Bank, one of the tiny portable ones, to power my Pi Zero, I need it to last at least 12 hours, but preferably 15 hours, for a comfortable safety cushion of time. My Pi would not be using WiFi and would only be using a USB sound card and a USB camera. The processor would be at 75-100% almost all the time. [This link](https://github.com/geerlingguy/raspberry-pi-dramble/wiki/Power-Consumption) shows the power consumption of the Pi Zero, which at max is 800mA. So what size power bank would I need to purchase?

Comment: Depends on the power consumption of the additional peripherals. Other than that, what's the question? 800 mA * 15 h * safety factor >= 12.000 mAh

Comment: Nice find with the power consumption stats by the way.

Comment: In other words a huge one.  Also, many power banks seem to be "marketing" rated by the amp-hour capacity of their cell at the ~4v cell voltage - conservation of energy means you will have a lower amp-hour capacity available to draw after conversion to the higher 5v USB rail even with perfect DC-DC conversion, and the conversion is of course not perfectly efficient.   You may want to look at something more like a large gel-cell and an efficient buck regulator.  Even better, try to find a lower power consumption solution to your task, or a platform amenable to sleeping and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For power saving tips:
Have a look @ Raspberry Pi Zero - Conserve power and reduce draw to 30mA
http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/raspberry-pi-zero-conserve-energy

Comment: While powersaving is of course a good and valid point (e.g. no HDMI in this application). Comparing idle values however are of little use here - after all the Pi has some work to do and just idle around all day ;)