# What is the minimum power supply needed for PiZero?

Tags: power, pi-zero

What is the minimum power supply needed for PiZero?
I want to know the numbers in terms of Voltage and amperes.
I want to build a cluster of Pis.

Comment: Related (giving links to measurements of power consumption): http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39255/powering-the-pi-from-battery-power-consumption/39273#39273 http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38775/powering-raspberry-pi-zero-from-a-usb-power-bank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum is really small. A good quality phone charger may even serve the purpose.

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/40393/24224

Comment: I was looking for that link as a dupe. Thanks for pointing to it!